# Probability calculation for diabetes prediction

Tags: probability

I have collected diabetes patient details. Each user details contains his symptoms, he might have diabetes in symptoms and might not have.

Currently what I am doing:

If patient A have x and y symptoms. And we find 20 patients who have x and y along with diabetes as a symtoms out of 100 patients.
So we count A has 20℅(20/100) probability of having diabetes.

Is this correct way of predicting diabetes possibility for the patient?

I appreciate if someone help me to make it more intuitive or may way to play with probablity value.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it is try to figure out what is the underlying **probability distribution** of the random variable you are interested on, use your data to calculate the parameters of this distribution, and then calculated the desired probability. In your case you want 'the probability that the patient $p_i$ has diabetes', given the information of that patient you have in your data set.

When you ask if 0.2 is the probability of diabetes for a patient with $x$ and $y$ what you are saying is that you are using the simplest probability distribution possible, not considering any other data besides $x$ and $y$. Under the assumption of this simplest model your answer is correct, but probably in a real world this assumption would never be a real assumption.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. But I dont understand what other parameters I consider and how.

Answer (score 0):

That is basic probability theory. The short answer it would be, look for a known probability distribution that might suits you data and calculate the MLE. If you do not understand this I would recommend to start studying statistical inference from scratch. The long answer is that there is actually a lot of different ways to do this, you can use this classic approach, or a bayesian approach, or a machine learning approach, or etc, etc, etc... In a professional scenario I would go for the state-of-the-art and see what are the current models people is using to this problem, one example is bellow where the authors use decision trees mixed with a markov model under a monte carlo framework. But it depends on your background, as I said if you do not know what a MLE is, then probably you need to study probability and inference from scratch.

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2394709/

Comment: I know machine learning techniques like naive  bayea, svm, NN. But my data is not that good which can be used to predict the prediction. Show being at safer side, using rule based approach with probablity calculation looks good to me